# Is is possible to access secret manager from end user impersonation on local?

Tags: google-secret-manager

I have been able to access my secret from secret manager on google with a service account and its key file but I would like to be able to do this using the access token I generate with my end user on local that is impersonating the app engine service account. I was wondering if this is possible/ looking for some guidance.

I have looked at the documentation for authenticating a service account and the client library for secret manager and other but I cannot find anything about using a access token to gain access to a secret form a local machine.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I'm not sure what code you'd need? I used the google cloud console to create the secret, give the service account secret accessor rights, and download key file. I used my local gcloud sdk to impersonate the service account to generate an access token. I am just wondering if it is possible to set up authentication using an access token instead of a service account key.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here.  1. Make sure you're only granting access to the specific secrets you need.  2. You don't need to create a service account key to impersonate a service account. Grant your user roles/serviceAccountUser permissions on the service account. Why not just grant your user account access to the secret?  3. Auth to gcloud as yourself (`gcloud auth login --update-adc`).  4. gcloud actually mints an access token from the authed credential, so you can't provide your own right now.  5. Call the API directly with the token in the `Authorization` header with `Bearer` prefix.

Comment: Yes I only created the key to access the secret to test it out. I would like to use my user as an impersonation and the access token instead. The one I get when I run
`gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account [SA_FULL_EMAIL]`
I followed these docs for setting up authentication for the secret, https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries, but couldn't find anything else using the token.

Comment: It'd be something like `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"`. However, why not just grant your user account direct access to the secret? Then you can run `gcloud secrets access` directly. You can also run `gcloud secrets access --impersonate-service-account`. I'm still not understanding why you want to generate an access token for use with gcloud - it should never be required.

Comment: This helped thank you, I was able to access the secret from command line with user impersonation and curl. I guess what I was trying to do overall was to authenticate my environment so that it could use the SecretManagerServiceClient in PHP without having to download the key file, like in the docs in my previous comment.

Comment: Why not just authenticate to gcloud as yourself (`gcloud auth login --update-adc` and select you@email.com) - no service account required? You can grant your user account access to the secret.